# Flurry is not getting integrated in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, flurry

I just wanted to analyse how the flurry integration works so i created a simple 'Hello World' app in Android Studio.But somehow nothing is being shown on my flurry dashboard & even the events section. The Manifest file uses the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I have included FlurryAnalytics-4.1.0.jar in my lib folder.

The onStart() and onStop() methods in the Activity class look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "API_KEY");
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("Article_Read");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

However the logcat file shows some error :

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.VerifyError: com/flurry/sdk/dw
W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.dj$1.a(SourceFile:247)
W/System.err﹕ at com.flurry.sdk.ff.run(SourceFile:49)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: How long has it been since your events were reported by the app? I've noticed a delay between when data is sent and when it is shown on the dashboard, sometimes running to multiple hours.

Comment: it has been 2-3 days now. No events are getting tracked & nothing is shown on the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

I've integrated Flurry Analytics recently and I get the same warnings. These warnings don't seem to affect the reports getting back to Flurry. I Suggest checking your reports on the dashboard to see if they are making their way back there. I suspect that these warnings are linked to the advertising side of Flurry not being used, only the Analytics side.

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried integrating Flurry 4.1.0, and it doesn't seem to be working for me. Going back to 3.3.2 is though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the internet connectivity, if there is no internet connectivity, this exception will be thrown by flurry sdk:

```
09-11 10:37:21.570: W/dalvikvm(11122): VFY: unable to resolve static method 11523: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;.getAdvertisingIdInfo (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
09-11 10:37:21.570: D/dalvikvm(11122): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
09-11 10:37:21.575: W/FlurryAgent(11122): Start session with context: com.fexcon.warnersbay.HomeActivity@4270cc58 count:0
09-11 10:37:21.575: W/dalvikvm(11122): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1470 (Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;)
09-11 10:37:21.575: W/dalvikvm(11122): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x43
09-11 10:37:21.580: W/dalvikvm(11122): VFY:  rejected Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;.c ()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
09-11 10:37:21.580: W/dalvikvm(11122): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0043
09-11 10:37:21.580: W/dalvikvm(11122): VFY:  rejected Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;.c ()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
09-11 10:37:21.580: W/dalvikvm(11122): Verifier rejected class Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;
09-11 10:37:21.585: W/System.err(11122): java.lang.VerifyError: com/flurry/sdk/dw
09-11 10:37:21.600: W/System.err(11122):    at com.flurry.sdk.dj$1.a(SourceFile:247)
09-11 10:37:21.605: W/System.err(11122):    at com.flurry.sdk.ff.run(SourceFile:49)
09-11 10:37:21.615: W/System.err(11122):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-11 10:37:21.615: W/System.err(11122):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-11 10:37:21.615: W/System.err(11122):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 10:37:21.615: W/System.err(11122):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```